# how to use a void inside a case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, void

So I have a code like this...

in the .h

```
- (void)job1:(id)sender;
```

in the .m

i have a UIButton and also a case switch. and i want to make one of the cases, lets say case 1, have the same job like that button.

so I said that the action is the "job1" in the void.

and i wrote like this for the button:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {


    [_button addTarget:self action:@selector(job1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



}
```

And now in the case, i want case 1 to do the same thing.. "job1" from that void.
(i use the cases for table view, so each case is a cell)

```
switch(row){

     case 0: 

           //doesn't matter

        break;

     case 1: 

           // I want the same thing to happen here when this cell is pressed.
           // so how do i do that?
           // can i address the void "job1"?
           // if not, can i address the button ?

        break;
```

every help is appreciated.
thanks.

(I edited it to be more clear).

Comment: it is really weird but.... [self button:nil] in your switch-case will work

Comment: void is not a type. I guess you might mean nil but even then you can't really switch on nil because switch uses a primitive value so nil isn't a valid option. But equally it will work because nil equates to 0. Just all a bit weird.

Comment: its not working for me, and lets say the case is not 0, for example case 5.

Comment: I've read your question 5 times and still don't understand it.  If you want to invoke `job1`, just do `[self job1:someParm]`.  (BTW, `IBAction` translates as `void`.  It's only there to cue the interface builder to link to it.)

Comment: appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code outside of the button logic

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    [self doStuff];
}

- (void) caseFunction {
    switch (val) {
    case 0:
        [self doStuff];
        break;
    }
}

- (void) doStuff {
    // Code goes here
}
```